# jQuery each and width() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm giving the container #page-wrap the width that is combined width of the width of all the images inside of it using this code:

HTML

```
<div id="page-wrap" class="group">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <article class="post">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

JS

```
    var windowH = $(window).height();
    var windowW = $(window).width();

    if (windowW >= 751 && $('article img').length) { 
        $('article img').height(windowH -190); 
        $('article img').css('width', 'auto');
        var allArticleWidth = 0;
        $('article').each(function() {
            allArticleWidth += $(this).width() + 10; //10 is margin of post
        });
        $('#page-wrap').width(allArticleWidth); 
    }
```

But it doesn't work when the window is vertical; the width of #page-wrap is smaller than it should be.

Comment: Maybe there is some padding/margin you don't count? Try this instead: `allArticleWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);`

Comment: Do you have this javascript wrapped in a $(window).load(function(){ ... });

Comment: As long as it's $(window).load. $(document).ready triggers when the DOM is completely loaded but before other resources are loaded specifically images. So calculating widths of elements containing images in a $(document).ready function will give mixed results. Using $(window).load triggers once all resources have loaded including images.

Comment: Articles are block level elements just like a div. do you have some css setting them to display: inline-block;?

Comment: @GreggDuncan they are floating to left

Comment: How wide is your window when it is vertical? This line: if (windowW >= 751 && $('article img').length) stops your page-wrap resizing if the window is less than 752 pixels wide.

Comment: I'm out of help then. It works fine for me as long as the window is more than 752 pixels wide. Without something to clear the floats the height of the page-wrap is zero. but the width still creates the horizontal scrollbar. https://jsfiddle.net/7d8ujkrt/1/

Comment: I just noticed your code says "//10 is margin of post" is that both sides? because you are only adding image width + 10. If the margin is both sides you need to add 20. And if there are any borders or padding those need to be added as well.

Comment: @GreggDuncan hm no just margin left. no padding.

Comment: @GreggDuncan This seems to happen only when the viewport ratio is smaller than 4:3

Comment: I don't know if it will help but do you have this in the head of your html page: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Comment: @GreggDuncan I just realized that if the image width is bigger than the window width, jQuery gets the window width instead of the image width. How could I overcome this?

Comment: You could start out with CSS setting the image width when it loads. img { width: 1px; }. then your javascript can get an accurate window width and will resize your images accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gren Duncan, I began to pay attention to what's in the stylesheet, and found out there was max-width:100% for img that came with the foundation framework I'm using. So the jQuery was somehow getting the css max width of the image which couldn't be wider than the window width, instead of the actual outputted image width. I deleted the max-width since I didn't need it, and it solved the problem.